# How do you create destination columns in a custom SSIS component?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Stumbling through learning how to build custom SSIS components. There are plenty of examples of taking input, transforming it and send it to a fixed output column. I cannot, however, find any instruction on how to create fixed destination columns when creating input.

Here's a commercial component that's doing what I'm after:

[image]

All I'm trying to do is let the user select from among the available input columns and map them to a destination that I can track inside the component. So that I know, for example, that column X is a forename and column Y is a surname and so on.

Searching on this yields a lot about Destination Components in SSIS, but it's a Transformation I'm trying to build. How does one set up destination columns?

Comment: Is your destination column going to be dynamically named?

Comment: @digital.aaron Nope. I just need the user to be able to tell the component which columns in the input represent particular pieces of data that the component needs.

Comment: So the problem isn't creating the columns, but the actual mapping of the source to destination in the transformation step?

Comment: @digital.aaron It's both. I essentially need to re-create the dialogue shown, with input and destination columns. Right now I can handle inputs but I can't work out how to make any destination columns available for the user to map to. Appreciate you trying to help: I'm new to SSIS and working alone :(

Comment: Now worries! I've worked quite a bit with SSIS, but I've never exposed the transformation step before. I'm firing up Data Tools right now to explore a couple of potential ideas I have. I'll report back with what I find.

Answer (score 1):

The column list on the right side of the mapper (Available Destination Columns) is controlled by the ExternalMetadataColumnCollection of the Input you are using. So, if you created your input (`IDTSInput100`) by calling `ComponentMetadata.InputCollection.New()` you can use its `ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.New()` to create a new column in that list. You just have to set the column properties, the New() method adds the column to the list instantly.

If it is not the answer you were looking for, I may have misanderstood the question so please, let me know.

Comment: hi Daniel, I have the same problem as the author of the question. I tried using ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.New() method of the InputCollection, but no column is shown in the map tab...any help?

Comment: Sorry @Suxsem, I am not using SSIS for years now, I can't remember how I did that. Maybe the tools have changed also