# How to map input columns in custom SSIS destination component

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Ok, my issue is very similar to this one but the answer doesn't work for me: [How do you create destination columns in a custom SSIS component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488690/how-do-you-create-destination-columns-in-a-custom-ssis-component)

I'm building a custom SSIS destination component to upload some data (name and surname) to my web service (let's pretend there are no other already existing ways to do that).

Imagine the user is using a OLE DB source to read a SQL table with columns "First name" and "Last name" and connect this source component to my custom destination component.

**How can I allow the user to map the output columns of the source component (First name and Last name in this example) to my input columns (Name and Surname) so I can track them in the ProcessInput method?
**

This is the code I'm using to create the external columns, but as you can see the columns are not displayed anywhere in the mapping tab.

```
        public override void ProvideComponentProperties()
        {
            // Reset the component.  
            RemoveAllInputsOutputsAndCustomProperties();
            ComponentMetaData.RuntimeConnectionCollection.RemoveAll();

            IDTSInput100 input = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.New();
            input.Name = "Input";

            IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100 externalNameColumn = input.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.New();
            externalNameColumn.Name = "Name";
            externalNameColumn.Description = "The name of the customer";
            
            IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100 externalSurnameColumn = input.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.New();
            externalSurnameColumn.Name = "Surname";
            externalSurnameColumn.Description = "The surname of the customer";

            IDTSRuntimeConnection100 connection = ComponentMetaData.RuntimeConnectionCollection.New();
            connection.Name = "MyConnectionManager";
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot follow: Who is the user here (another DBA?) and how they are supposed to map those columns (in VS)?

Comment: Hi @wp78de, the user is who install my custom component in his system and design a ssis package that uses it. In the component properties there is an "input columns" tab (see the screenshot), I'm expecting the mapping to be done here by the user, am I wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally solved it, it was incredibly simple.

The mapping should be done in the *previous* component in the data flow, not in the destination one!

Just double click on the previous component (the one connected to your custom destination component) and set your preferred mapping in the column mapping tab.

Simple as that.